# Consulta geolocalización asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenos días quisiera que me puedan ayudar.
no se si se podrá realizar una Geolocalización con lenguaje asp.net.
es decir presionar y guardar en una tabla donde esta ubicado las calles o solo presionar y tomar foto las calles avenida de la geolocalización.
de donde estoy.

Bueno este es mi Codigo:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Get User Current Location using Google Map Geolocation API Service in asp.net website</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWkZwfPfeqw_tcUTsLcsLQh7T3vefrRII" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var city = position.coords.locality;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude + "" });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

me sale este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera algo como esto cuando presione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenos dias, puedes realizarlo, en el caso de obtener la geolocalizacion de algun lugar seleccionado, puedes apoyarte con una API de google maps, existe una amplia documentacion y te muestra un ejemplo, rescatar los datos y guardarlos es una tarea aparte pero nada fuera de lo comun. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=es-419

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara. Además, sería bueno que incluyeras el código que lleves hasta el momento y los errores o problemas con los que te estés encontrando.

Comment: @dev  ya edite mi pregunta mi amigosy puse mi codigo y el error

Comment: Gracias. He votado por reabrir tu pregunta, pero tengo una duda: parece que la geolocalización la estás intentando hacer con la API de Google Maps en JavaScript y no con C#, ¿es eso correcto?

Comment: Quieres presionar un botón y obtener el lugar donde estás, correcto?

Comment: @Pierro muestra algún error en consola ? Si es así  ¿ Qué error le muestra?

Comment: @fredyfx si correcto quiero que al presionar me indique donde estoy asi como google map y si es posible guardar las coordenadas. o la imagen cuando me mostro la geocolizacion.

Comment: @Dev.Joel amigo ya mostre la imagen de consola

Comment: con la respuesta que acabo de publicar obtienes el punto basado en Geolocalizacion y dibujado en google maps :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagen de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí funcionando: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-geolocation-api-tutorial-example/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
            function showlocation() {
               // One-shot position request.
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
            }

      function callback(position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

             document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
         document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;

        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLong
                });      

                marker.setMap(map);
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
      function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 1,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), 
                                          mapOptions);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
        <input type="button" value="Show my location on Map"
                onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />   <br/>
    </center>

        Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>       <br/>
        Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mi amigo si me da las coordenadas pero la imagen del mapa no se muestra. :( T_T

Comment: has visto el enlace?

Answer (score 2):

Aqui esta la respuesta :

para poder visualizar el mapa :
1. tienes que poner el codigo de la api key de google maps.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View side-by-side</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map, #pano {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 45%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>
    <script>

        function initialize() {
            var fenway = { lat: -12.0925034, lng: -77.05491230000001 };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: fenway,
                zoom: 14
            });
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                document.getElementById('pano'), {
                    position: fenway,
                    pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10
                    }
                });
            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOVmgMrLBpBMmHRlu7hqX7Ti3g-mmhiEE&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has incluido la libreria de google maps dos veces, elimina uno de los dos:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWkZwfPfeqw_tcUTsLcsLQh7T3vefrRII" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: lo borre uno igual me sale ese problema

Comment: @Pierro es lógica esta respuesta, por eso muestra el segundo error de Key, haciendo estos cambios es decir `src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWkZwfPfeqw_tcUTsLcsLQh7T3vefrRII&sensor=false&libraries=places"` , presenta los mismos errores?

Comment: @Dev.Joel si lo borre el segundo y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: podrias hacer una actualizacion del codigo para verifcar?